# Type Punning with Unions and Heap

Tags: c

I have read a lot about type punning and how it is not good to just use a cast.

```
oldType* data = malloc(sizeof(oldType));
((newtype*)data)->newElement;
```

This results in undefined behavior. So the solution is to use `union` so that the compiler knows that these two pointers are linked to one another so it doesn't do funny things with strict aliasing.

That being said the unions also looked like:

```
union testing
{
    struct test1 e;
    struct test2 f;
}
```

Is it defined behavior if pointers are used in the union?

```
union testing
{
    struct test1* e;
    struct test2* f;
}
```

Here is a full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test1
{
    int a;
    char b;
};

struct test2
{
    int c;
    char d;
};

union testing
{
    struct test1* e;
    struct test2* f;
};

void printer(const struct test2* value);

int main()
{
    struct test1* aQuickTest = malloc(sizeof(struct test1));
    aQuickTest->a = 42;
    aQuickTest->b = 'a';
    printer(((union testing)aQuickTest).f);
    ((union testing)aQuickTest.f)->c = 111; // using -> not .
    return 0;
}

void printer(const struct test2* value)
{
    printf("Int: %i Char: %c",value->c, value->d);
}
```

Or would I need to use unions without pointers. And then use `printer(&(((union testing)aQuickTest).f));` (with the `&`) to get the address of `f`.

Comment: Make your `union` contain `struct test1 e;` and `struct test2 f;`, then you can use the `union` type to hold either value and take the address (e.g. `&myunion.f`)  to provide a pointer to either without running afoul of the strict aliasing rule. (but note since one will reference an `int` and the other a `char`, your results may not be meaningful)

Comment: There were some good answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56401445/type-punning-and-malloced-memory It is all about *access* so there really is no way to get this model to conform to strict aliases because two different types are trying to access the same data. Which ever type sets that memory value has to be the **same** type to read it back. I'm sure there is a way to perhaps get to it using unions.

Comment: Except that a cast from any type to a `char` type (and back) is specifically allowed under the Standard and is not type-punning by definition. See: [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is non-conforming to cast to a union type, as your code does:

> ```
>     printer(((union testing)aQuickTest).f);
> ```

For that reason, your code does have undefined behavior as far as the Standard is concerned.

More directly to the point, however, no, your approach of putting pointers into a union does not avoid strict aliasing violations with respect to the pointed-to types, even without the casting issue.  In your case, the effect is that where your `union testing` is in scope, implementations cannot assume that objects of type `struct test1 **` and `struct test2 **` do not alias each other.  That does not prevent undefined defined behavior resulting from accessing an object with effective type `struct test1` through an lvalue of type `struct test2`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The idea of casting came from: https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/04/using-pointers-to-recast-in-c-is-bad.html I didn't was gcc specific code but if that still does UB that isn't good. Would there be a way to make a macro that can accomplish this?

Comment: It appears that casting to a union is gcc specific.

Comment: @Questionable, if you have an existing macro with members of the needed types, then yes, you can write a macro for the reinterpretation through a union, using a cast to a union *pointer* instead of to the union type itself.  But you cannot *generate* such a union generically with a macro in standard C, because doing so requires `typeof` or an equivalent, which standard C does not have.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to type pun types `X` and `Y`, you should use the union -

```
typedef union {
    X x;
    Y y;
}X_Y;
```

This allows you to share the bit representation of X with Y and vice versa. 
If you use -

```
typedef union {
    X* x;
    Y* y;
}X_Y_p;
```

you are sharing the bit representations for the pointer. For a system that uses the same bit representation for all pointer, you are essentially casting pointer of `X` to pointer of `Y`, which you identified causes Undefined Behaviour.

It is not illegal to have something `X_Y_p` because `X*` and `Y*` are types by themselves. But they achieve something different. They let you type pun pointers, which is not what you want to do (and not necessary in most cases, because pointers share representation on *most* systems). A cast should be fine there.