# Type punning and malloc'ed memory

Tags: c

I originally asked this question: [Type Punning with Unions and Heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398362/type-punning-with-unions-and-heap)

And not wanting the question to keep evolving to the point that anyone reading in the future had no idea what the original question was, I have a spin off question.

After reading this site:
https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2016/05/type-based-aliasing-in-c.html

Near the bottom it talks about malloc'd memory. Is it safe to say that casting from one pointer type to another pointer type is safe when memory is on the heap?

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test1
{
    int a;
    char b;
};

struct test2
{
    int c;
    char d;
};

void printer(const struct test2* value);

int main()
{
    struct test1* aQuickTest = malloc(sizeof(struct test1));
    aQuickTest->a = 42;
    aQuickTest->b = 'a';
    printer((struct test2*)aQuickTest); //safe because memory was malloc'd???
    return 0;
}

void printer(const struct test2* value)
{
    printf("Int: %i Char: %c",value->c, value->d);
}
```

And guessing it might not be safe. What would be the proper way to do this with memcpy? I will attempt to write an example with a function of what might hopefully work?

```
struct test2* converter(struct test1* original);

int main()
{
    struct test1* aQuickTest = malloc(sizeof(struct test1));
    aQuickTest->a = 42;
    aQuickTest->b = 'a';
    struct test2* newStruct = converter(aQuickTest);
    printer(newStruct);
    return 0;
}

struct test2* converter(struct test1* original)
{
    struct test2* temp;
    memcpy(&temp, &original, sizeof(struct test2));
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Casting pointer types is always safe. It may become undefined behevior when you dereference the pointer, if the data stored at the location is not compatible with the pointer type.

Comment: `Is it safe to say that casting from one pointer type to another pointer type is safe when memory is on the heap?` depends on what you want to do. Casting is ok. But once in your code you access the underlying object using different handle, ie. `value->c`,  it becomes undefined.

Comment: Is there anyway to get around it being undefined? It appears that memcpy is supposed to help with this, but I don't see any examples utilizing pointers.

Comment: No. There is none. And there shouldn't be any. Accessing memory using invalid handle is UB. Dot. Your `converter` function is invalid from top to bottom anyway, as you copy pointer values, not memory behind pointers.

Comment: Is this why some code passes around so many void*. The goal being that you just want to pass around "memory" and don't want the compiler trying to interpret what the ones and zeros actually mean?

Comment: The rules say, that you can access any memory using `a character type` [C11 6.5.p7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7). The `void*` type is used, because it is a "generic" pointer, ie. you can cast any pointer into `void*` type. The goal is to "pass a pointer to something unknown". `what the ones and zeros actually mean?` - The goal is to pass a _pointer_, not memory. There could be valid memory behind the pointer, there could be none. In the end, you need to cast the pointer to compatible type to access it. The goal is to write uniform interface, API, that you can pass any type.

Comment: In the "early" days of C, when there was no `void*` type, people used `char*` to represent "pointer to unknown type". Anyway, we can imagine an architecture, where for example `sizeof(int*) >  sizeof(char*)`. So if you ware to cast `int*` pointer value to `char*` pointer, you would loose some information (from the pointer value). That's why `void*` was invented - so you could pass data to unknown storage. It becomes more important on architectures with `__far` and `__near` pointers and where pointers have different size depending on the type.

Comment: Thank you this is all very good information. Some of the information on the internet gets murky when it comes to these specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void *pnt = malloc(sizeof(struct test1));
```

What type has the memory behind pnt pointer? No type. It is uninitialized (it's value is "indeterminate"). There is just "memory".

Then you do:

```
struct test1* aQuickTest = malloc(sizeof(struct test1));
```

You only cast the pointer. Nothing happens here. No assembly is generated. Reading uninitialized memory is undefined behavior tho, so you can't read from `aQuickTest->a` (yet). But you can assign:

```
aQuickTest->a = 1;
```

This writes to an object `struct test1` in the memory. This is assignment. You can now read `aQuickTest->a`, ie. print it.
But the following

```
printf("%d", ((struct test2*)aQuickTest)->a);
```

is undefined behavior (although it will/should work). You access the underlying object (ie. `struct test1`) using a not matching pointer type `struct test2*`. This is called "strict alias violation". Dereferencing an object (ie. doing `->` or `*`) using a handle of not [compatible type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type) results in undefined behavior. It does not matter that `struct test1` and `struct test2` "look the same". They are different type. The rule is in [C11 standard 6.5p7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7).

In the first code snipped undefined behavior happens on inside `printf("Int: %i Char: %c",value->c`. The access `value->` accesses the underlying memory using incompatible handle.

In the second code snipped the variable `temp` is only a pointer. Also `original` is a pointer. Doing `memcpy(&temp, &original, sizeof(struct test2));` is invalid, because `&temp` writes into the `temp` pointer and `&original` writes into the `original pointer. No to the memory behind pointers. As you write out of bounds into`&temp`pointer and read of bounds from`&original`pointer (because most probably`sizeof(temp) < sizeof(struct test2)`and`sizeof(original) < sizeof(struct test2)`), undefined behavior happens.

Anyway even if it were:

```
    struct test1* original = &(some valid struct test1 object).
    struct test2 temp;
    memcpy(&temp, original, sizeof(struct test2));
    printf("%d", temp.a); // undefined behavior
```

*accessing* the memory behind `temp` variable is still invalid. As the `original` didn't had `struct test2` object, it is still invalid. `memcpy` doesn't change the type of the object in memory.

Comment: So if I did `void* memoryPointer = malloc(sizeof(struct* test1));` Then I could cast another pointer `struct test1* aQuickTest = (struct test1* memoryPointer);` I could assign a value. `aQuickTest->a = 3;` and later if I do `struct test2* newStruct = (struct test2*)memoryPointer;` I could read the values because I am not actually recasting from one defined type to another.

Comment: The casting does not matter, the access matters. If you initialized the memory using `((struct test1*)memoryPointer)->a = 3` then you cannot access the memory using `(struct test2*)memoryPointer`. No matter what pointers (types?) you have in the way. The _access_ is using incompatible types.

Comment: So `newStruct.c = 4;` would still not work even though all the memory would be aligned properly? Or in other words, there is no way to do this other than casting `void*` to a `union` of `struct`s to get the memory to alias properly?

Comment: Ok, I think it helped a lot to state that `newStruct.c = 4` initializes it as a new type. Whatever type initializes the value is the only type that can read back (access) the value. Period :D

Comment: If I had `struct A { int x; }` and `struct B { struct A y; int z; }`. I could safely do `struct B* testing = malloc(sizeof(struct B)); struct A* testing2 = (struct A*)testing; testing2->x = 5;` then later do `testing->y.x` and have no issues because the actual value is being *accessed* from a `struct A` type.

Comment: Upvoted, but I think your last point about `memcpy()` is mistaken.  The definedness of that function's behavior is not conditional on the types of the objects to which its arguments point.

Comment: Re “is undefined behavior (although it will/should work)”: No.